# Regex for all occurences between a single character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to find the regex expression that takes all occurences between a character ("|" in this case). The number of occurrences of "|" could vary.
So the following:

> abc|def|ghijk|l|mnopqrs|tuvwxyz

would ideally return a list of: ['def', 'ghijk', 'l', 'mnopqrs'].

The best result I get from the following regex expression:

```
"\|(.*)\|"
```

but this generates evertyhing between the first and last occurence, so I thought of working around this problem with a loop, but there sure must be a better solution. I am using the re module in Python 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Forget regexps, just use the `split` method of strings. `In []: "abc|def|ghijk|l|mnopqrs|tuvwxyz".split("|")
Out]: ['abc', 'def', 'ghijk', 'l', 'mnopqrs', 'tuvwxyz']`

Comment: Split doesn't work because it returns abc and tuvwxyz, which are not required.

Comment: @RudyTheHunter so discard the first and last result. It hardly means the solution "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following RegEx:

```
(?<=\|)([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\|)
```

Here  is a working example:  [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W0qrsd/1)

This uses a Look-behind `(?<=\|)` to make sure that the letters are preceeded by the pipe and a look-ahead `(?=\|)` to make sure that the letters are followed by a pipe.

Comment: You don't really need a capture group, since the whole match captures the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I needed to add 0-9 in the brackets, since there were also numbers involved in the "real" case. I didn't know the look-ahead an look-behind, which is really cool!

Answer (score 0):

`"\|(.*)\|"`
This does a greedy match.. i.e. Matches from 1st till the last occurrence of `|` symbol. Greedy in lay man terms is matching as much as possible. (using just `*`). Non-greedy is matching as less as possible (using `*?`).

What you need is a global non-greedy match. 
`"\|(.*?)\|"`

But for your use-case, a split by `|` symbol would be more appropriate as mentioned by @jsbueno

Comment: Thanks! I am going to have a look at the differences between greedy/non-greedy matching.